# Designer 2010 Workflow does not overwrite old version when published

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Whenever I publish a workflow from the Designer, the workflow will create a new workflow instead of updating the old one.

For example:

- Workflow A is published as a list workflow and can be manually started by users
- Workflow A gets published again. Users can now start two workflows "Workflow A" and "Workflow A (1)" instead of just the new one

Is there a setting to turn on overwriting for workflows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time a new workflow is published within SPD, a new instance is added. What this means is that each time a workflow is published, it overwrites a previous version but the previous versions are not removed. If an administrator were to check the active workflows, they'd see a history that looks like this.  This is to allow any items that still have "in-progress" workflows to complete successfully.

[image]

The latest workflow version will have name "Workflow A".

You can manually remove those workflows by opening up the Workflow Settings page of that List.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but my problem is that the new version of the workflow is called "Workflow A (1)" while the old version remains "Workflow A". Both can be started by users. I want to achieve what is seen on your screenshot.

Comment: After deleting all workflows for the list and re-deploying them via SPD the workflows finally updated themselves instead of creating new versions with different numbers behind the name.